# Construction of a nowhere dense perfect set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

I have to construct for every $\varepsilon > 0$ a nowhere dense perfect set $\mathit K \subseteq [0,1]$ with $\lambda(K) > 1 - \varepsilon$.
A hint is to do it similar as constructing the Cantor set.

I know that the Lebesgue measure of the Cantor set is zero, so $\lambda(C) = 0$.

I also know that the Cantor set can be constructed as follows:
$\mathcal C = [0,1]\backslash \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} \cup_{k=0}^{3^n-1} \left(\frac{3k+1}{3^{n+1}},\frac{3k+2}{3^{n+1}} \right)$.

Unfortunately the hint doesn't help me too much. What would be a good way to start tackling this?

Edit: Do I understand correctly that because $\mathit K \subseteq [0,1]$ the Lebesgue measure $\lambda (K)$ can at mostly be 1?

Comment: Instead of removing the middle third of each interval, remove some $\delta_n>0$. By choosing the sequence $\{\delta_n\}_n$ appropriately, you can get the set to have "large" measure. And yes, $\lambda(K)\le 1$ simply because $A\subset B\to \lambda(A)\le\lambda(B)$.

Comment: @Reveillark thanks!  If I understand it correctly, I should replace $\left(\frac{3k+1}{3^{n+1}}, \frac{3k+2}{3^{n+1}}\right)$ by something of the form $\left(\delta_{n+1}, \delta_{n+2}\right)$ ?